# Can't override Paypal Buy Now button return url

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I'm trying to do something very simple, and it doesn't seem to work no matter what I do. I create a buy now button in paypal's backend and put the code in my site. I then add a return url in the form html so that I can do some post transaction stuff... i use this tag

```
'<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:8080?trans=1234567890">'
```

doesn't matter if it's localhost or not, it still returns to the url i specified in my auto return settings in paypals backend. Here is my entire button code... is anything missing from it?

```
var html = '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"> ' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> ' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:8080?trans=1234567890">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="'+ attr.id +'"> ' +
                    '<input type="image" src="http://invisibled.com/myimg.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt=""> ' +
                    '<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> ' +
                '</form>';
```

All i need is to specify a variable on the end of the return url... this will be an id to the item the user purchased so i can give them a download link. I REALLY don't want to have to set up anything too involved with the paypal API, I feel like there must be a way to get this working.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to why it's ignoring my form's return url and just using the return url you HAVE to specify in the backend?

Thanks!

============ EDIT ===============

i've updated my code as the user below has suggested... but still getting the same return to the url in my paypal settings

```
var html = '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> ' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@email.com">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://invisiblesound.net?t=1234567890" />' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Beat 0001">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="40">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">' +
                    '<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">' +
                    '<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">' +
                '</form>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a hosted button.  As such, the checkout will use the settings that were included with the button when you created it as opposed to looking at the variables you add to the form (apart from a few acceptions).

If you want to set dynamic variables in the form directly you'll need to use a non-hosted button, which of course makes the button not as secure.  If that's a big worry for you then you could move to the API's instead of using Payments Standard, which would give you much more freedom and still good protection.

Also, keep in mind that localhost isn't going to work when you actually go live.  You'll need to make sure you're setting an actual domain/IP there instead.  It might work for you during testing because you do indeed have a localhost configured, but your users won't.

Comment: hey man, I switched my code to manually create the item... but still it's returning to the url in my auto return settings... not the one specified here. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Why do you have it set both places?  I thought the return URL in the button would override your profile, but I really don't work with Payments Standard all that much, so that may just be incorrect.  Try disabling auto-return in your profile and see if it does it then.